# Grails hasOne Relationship without belongsTo

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

When going through documentation to work on hasOne relationship without belongsTo it throws an error

> hasOne property [Face.nose] is not bidirectional. Specify the other side of the relationship!.

Its just an example, in my usecase if i delete the nose i should not delete the face.So how to make it work without using belongsTo?

```
class Face {
..
static hasOne = [nose: Nose]
}
class Nose {
Face face
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your path here is to not use the `hasOne` keyword.

```
class Face {
  Nose nose
}

class Nose {
  Face face
}
```

Either can exist independently of the other, but both have references to each other.